# How can I tell if I'm still listening on a socket in Android

Tags: android, tcp

I'm responsible for some code on an Android device which talks to a PC over WiFi via a wireless access point (WAP), using TCP sending packets back and forth.  On the PC side the software uses winsock to send and receive packets with the Android device, but I have no access to, or control over, the PC side of this connection.

This architecture works fine sending and receiving, but if there is no traffic for **exactly 1 minute**, then if the PC attempts to send a packet to the Android it gets an RST back, as though the Android is no longer listening.    Winsock, on the PC side, is interpreting this is a timeout.

The Android device is configured to keep the WiFi "always on".     I'm using a java.net (Android API 16) socket in my code. Is there something I can check on that socket periodically, or an event I can receive to see if I've stopped listening?

**(Edit)**  I'm specifically referring to whether the Android is **listening**.   After 1 minute the Android device can still **send**.   Here's a Wireshark trace that illustrates this:

- 11    10.1.2.1    10.1.2.11   TCP 79  42825→181 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=8170 Len=13 7
- 12    10.1.2.11   10.1.2.1    TCP 89  181→40574 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=14 Win=259 Len=23
- 13    10.1.2.1    10.1.2.11   TCP 60  40574→181 [RST] Seq=14 Win=0 Len=0

The Android is 10.1.2.1, the PC is 10.1.2.11.   In this example I initiated a send from the Android TO the PC, and it went just fine.  The PC tried to send something in response, but the Android sent an [RST]

Also N.B. that this only refers to TCP - if the PC tries to ping the Android after 1 minute it still gets a response, but ping is ICMP.

**Edit 2**

Someone wanted to see how I create the socket.    So here it is:

```
new SocketPermission(new String(new StringBuilder(configLGIP).append(":180-")), "connect,accept,listen");            
 // Open a socket to the front end
 Log.d("StartTCP", "attempt IP " + configLGIP);
 try {
    sock = new Socket(configLGIP, 180 + SafeActivity.pdanum);
 }
```

Later I do...

```
if (sock != null) try {
    sock.setTcpNoDelay(true); 
    bin = new BufferedInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
```

Comment: I think adding some code to show how you create your TCP connection (and with what configuration) on Android side might be helpful to provide you a meaningful answer.

Comment: OK, I've added it but I'm not sure how it helps since it's just a generic Socket.   The question is really about how, in Android, I can tell if I'm listening, or if I can be notified if I've stopped listening.

Comment: Just FYI I think you actually want to determine if the socket is still *connected*, not if it's *listening*.  They are two different things, and the socket listening or not wouldn't have anything to do with your issue.

Comment: Well, as I showed in the Wireshark trace, I can still send (doesn't that mean we're connected?), but when someone sends a packet to me they get an RST.  That's why I was drawing the distinction.

Comment: You could make timer and send packets periodically, like `keep alive`.

Comment: Why not check for session_id and as soon as this changes, reconnect.

Comment: As alzee said the listening side is the server part, the PC in your case. The title should be : "How can I tell if I'm still connected on a socket in Android". If the client port changes that means a reconnect occurred between both send-reply. Make sure there's not some bug in your code that causes disconnections.

Comment: @sinistro  "**Why not check for session_id and as soon as this changes, reconnect**"   . . .  I don't understand  -  check WHEN for session ID?   Android, in general, is event driven so is there an event I can register for when the session ID changes?

Comment: @Tonteria24 _Make sure there's not some bug in your code that causes disconnections_  . . . if by "your" code, you mean the Android then that's the whole point of this stack overflow question - how do I tell if I'm disconnected if I don't get an error when I send?  I don't understand what you're suggesting.

Comment: @user316117 You will have to write code to fire an event in case this changes.

Comment: @Sinistro   What does this mean?  I do I tell if it changes if there's no event in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You have to Communicating Devices.

- Android Device
- and PC

Your android device is sending a RST Flag which means, that no service available on the addressed Port.

Programmatically In Order to detect such FLAG and respectively the unavailable Service,

**create your own TCP Datagram by implementing a raw socket interface**.

In this Case you can analyse the headers of the Datagram.  Implementing such Socket require an administrative privileges (which i think you have on the PC side).

Here's [more infos hier](http://www.tenouk.com/Module43a.html) !

Hope I can help

Comment: The example you linked to seems to assume direct programming at the Linux root level.    But this is stock Android, not a rooted device, and I have no programmatic access to the PC, so I only have access to what I can see from the **Android API**, as I explained in the original question.   So I'm not sure how your answer relates to my question.   This is really a very simple **Android programming question** - how do I get notified of a change in the Android's port or socket status?